# How to increase performance of this code snippet by assembly?

Tags: performance, assembly

How can I increase performance of the following code snippet in assembly? Please suggest what ways I have in order to do this?

```
void changeDirection(char key) {
    /*
      W
    A + D
      S

    */
    switch (key) {
    case 'w':
        if (direction != 2) direction = 0;
        break;
    case 'd':
        if (direction != 3) direction = 1;
        break;
    case 's':
        if (direction != 4) direction = 2;
        break;
    case 'a':
        if (direction != 5) direction = 3;
        break;
    }
}/******increase performance*****/
```

Thanks

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee any modern compiler will turn that into faster assembly than the vast majority of developers could produce by hand :-)

Comment: Surely this only runs once per game tick anyway?

Comment: impossible to say without the surrounding context.  Producing optimal asm for just mapping an ASCII digit to a number isn't useful if this inlines into other code that does something conditional based on the number.  Hopefully `direction` is `static` or something so the compiler can optimize it into a register more easily when inlining this function.

Comment: What hardware do you want to optimize this for?  I assume not x86, since any decent compiler should make fast enough code  for this function, even for real 8086 hardware (i.e. truly ancient and slow stuff).

Comment: If your game is slow, I doubt that THIS function is the bottleneck, it's done in just a few cycles. Can you explain what makes you think this should be improved?

Comment: so you test direction for values 2..5, but output new values in range 0..3 ... dare you elaborate on this one? (it makes quite a difference, if you would go from 0-3 to 0-3, it would allow for more tricks). (besides that already commented thing, that's this can't be bottleneck of anything, so it's pointless to optimize it, but just for pointlessness I actually would, if it would make sense at first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in the end the 2-5 range vs 0-3 range turned out to be simple to abuse (although I'm afraid it's not what you wanted).

Plus normal games allow for key redefinition, which would break this completely. So this is more like "joke" than serious answer. But your question is on the brink of "joke" too, I mean: you have more serious problems if you really believe that the thing in your post is a problem.

```
// I expect "direction" to be int, otherwise change wantDir vars

void changeDirection2(char key) {
  //                                     a      s  d          w
  constexpr static int wantDir[] = { ~0, 3, ~0, 2, 1, ~0, ~0, 0 };
  int wantedDir = wantDir[key&7];
  if (wantedDir+2 == direction) return;
  direction = wantedDir;
}
```

Plus this will react to many more (all of them) keys than a,w,s,d. It's up to caller call only with correct ones.

---

version 2, without LUT (still hardcoded to "awsd" and mangling any other key into some number):

```
void changeDirection3(char key) {
  int wantedDir = (~key>>1)&3;
  if (wantedDir+2 == direction) return;
  direction = wantedDir;
}
```

Comment: I would upvote except that having an upvoted answer would prevent the question from being auto-deleted in 30 days.  If it's called *really* frequently this LUT is actually not bad.  Hmm, what if you avoid cache missed by implementing the LUT as a variable-count right shift by `key*4`, and then taking the low nibble?  So the LUT is just a 32-bit constant that you `mov` into a register.

Comment: `shl edi, 2`/ `mov eax, 0x0FF12F3F` / `shrx eax, eax, edi` / `and eax, 0x0F`.  Maybe cmov to handle the branch, so the store to `direction` always happens.  Or not, since branching to avoid the store will (in that case only) avoid a loop-carried dependency chain on `direction` if it's in a tight loop.  (Dunno why it would be for this case, but if you were using this idea for something where the optimization is relevant...)

Comment: @PeterCordes actually I didn't understand "right shift" after quick read and I had to do something for few secs before turning back to LCD, so my mind meanwhile "figured it out". `wantedDir = ((key>>1)^3)&3;` ... then I read your proposal again, hm. :)